# Generating reports on Opportunities having Related list with contradictory conditions

Tags: opportunity, picklist, joined-reports

I have an custom  Object Eval which is having lookup relation with Opportunities object. This Object Eval having a field ' Type ' which is of type pick-list with some values like 'A','B','C'

If two Eval  records one of type 'A'  and another of type 'B' are having lookup with same Opportunity record OppSample1 .

I was generating a joined report on Opportunities object with conditions like

1. For 1st bock

   Opportunities with  Eval  Type Equals  A
2. For 2nd bock

   Opportunities with  Eval  Type Not-Equals  A

Now both the report blocks showing OppSample1 , because OppSample1 record having 
2 Eval records related to it.one is of type A and another is of type not A.

So i was looking is there any way like when i filter report with condition

Opportunities with  Eval  Type Not-Equals  A  should not return OppSample1 record because it is having one related record which is of Type A.

Comment: Why not just group by Opportunity?

Comment: @Eric Yes Eric , that's a good idea.But i was just checking will there be any chance to make this happen without grouping